# How to do Pop in Popout whole view in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, zooming

I have four views in ViewController as an iPad app. Each view has a different controller of buttons and charts.I need to when the user clicks the particular view I need to make pop out the whole view. How can I achieve this any help?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a proper way, i suggest to pop out your VIEW with a little animation. 
First add the CAAnimationDelegate in you **.h** file:

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <CAAnimationDelegate>
```

Then on your **.m** file

```
   CABasicAnimation *goOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
   goOut.delegate = self; 
   // Choose animation duration in seconds, 0 if you dont want.
   [goOut setDuration:0.5]; 
   [goOut setRepeatCount:0];
   // You can play with A and B to specify the direction from where your VIEW will leave the screen
   [goOut setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(VIEW.center.x + A, VIEW.center.y + B)]]; 
   [VIEW.layer addAnimation:goOut forKey:@"position"];
```

Finally just hide the VIEW

```
    - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
         if (flag) {
              [VIEW setHidden:YES];
         }
    }
```

***Now if you want that your VIEW changes its frame and get the screen size just change***

```
    CABasicAnimation *goOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [goOut setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(VIEW.center.x + A, VIEW.center.y + B)]];
    [VIEW.layer addAnimation:goOut forKey:@"position"];
```

TO

```
     CABasicAnimation *goOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
     [goOut setToValue: [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)]];
     [VIEW.layer addAnimation:goOut forKey:@"bounds.size"];
```

And dont hide your VIEW in this case ;)

Comment: Mohamed Sadock I need to create one more view?

Comment: No, no need. Just replace VIEW by the clicked view